# synIDattr returns nothing in function

Tags: vimscript, neovim, echo

I have this part of code:

```
function! Test()
    echom synIDattr(synID(line('.'), col('.'), 1), 'name')
endfunction

autocmd TextChangedI <buffer> call Test()
```

I expected that every time I change some stuff the current "type" would be printed out. For example, if I'm in a commentary line of vim, I'd expect to see that at the bottom: `vimLineComment`. But nothing pops up.

If I enter

```
:echom synIDattr(synID(line('.'), col('.'), 1), 'name')
```

I'm getting my expected output. What am I doing wrong?

I've also tried this (which was written in `:h synIDattr`):

```
echo synIDattr(synIDtrans(synID(line("."), col("."), 1)), "name")
```

But it also doesn't work inside my `Test()` function:

```
function! Test()
    echo synIDattr(synIDtrans(synID(line("."), col("."), 1)), "name")
endfunction

autocmd TextChangedI <buffer> call Test()
```

If I insert `echom "Test"` I'm getting `Test` at the bottom everytime if I enter something. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you're typing in an area of text that matches defined syntax? I tried your code and nothing shows up if, say, I'm on an empty line but if I start inserting in the middle of something with syntax highlighting it works. Another illustration: type on the same line as `endif` in a function. Cursor before `endif`: success, cursor after `endif`: nothing. Which makes sense.

Comment: Oh wait, if I do that what you said, than I'm getting it as well. Hm.... I thought that it would work more "in general" and not in this "specifique" cases. Looks like I have to look for something else... Thank you! Could please write that as an answer so I can tick this question as answered? And what do you mean with "Which makes sense."? Is it because this function is written like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The provided code seemed to be working when I tried it and we established that OP is seeing the same behavior as I am. So that leaves a difference in expectations, I think, about what the correct behavior is.

Three important pieces of information:

1. Text colored by syntax highlighting is selected by rules, often regex patterns, and
   they specify where a matching block of text ends.
2. If you start appending text to the end of a line the cursor will usually be *beyond* the end of one of those defined blocks and so, naturally, you won't be inside a syntax item and nothing will be displayed by the autocmd/function.
3. In Normal mode the cursor is less likely to be beyond the end of a block since even after running `$` it sits *on top of* the last character of the line rather than beyond it.

The example I gave in a comment was entering text before and after and `endif` statement in a vimscript function. With the former you'll see something like `VimFuncBody` but with the latter nothing will be displayed. Conversely, with the cursor at the end of the same line in Normal mode if you enter `:call Test()` you'll see `VimCommand`. Hopefully the three points above explain all this behavior.

Ah, but what about a line that begins with `"`, i.e. a line comment. Since the pattern for that extends to the end of the line (regex `$`) we should see `vimlineComment` when adding to the end of the comment but we dont! Well, no, because with `" my comment` the block ends on that final `t` (`$` is a zero-width match) but the cursor is *beyond* that when we begin appending to the line.

(Admittedly, that last case is a little troubling because the text you type actually gets the appropriate comment color. Seems like a quirk of the implementation. Clearly dynamic text coloring and the output of `synID*()` don't operate by precisely the same rules and/or the same refresh timings.)

Comment: Good explanation! Thank you so much sir! c(^-^)c

Comment: No problem. Cheers.